# Sign-In with google returns a blank page using firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

> Hi Everyone . I am trying to setup google authentication with
>   firebase. So I have this signInWithPopup method on my auth object. But
>   when i click on the button its giving me a blank tab instead of list
>   of google accounts to select from. I am using firebase npm package.

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);

export const auth = firebase.auth();
export const firestore = firebase.firestore();

const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
provider.setCustomParameters({ prompt: 'select_account' });
export const signInWithGoogle = () => auth.signInWithPopup(provider);

export default firebase;
```

This is my code.. Can somebody please help